# Calculate running total while inserting into temporary table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below query which is calculating the total. I want to calculate running total instead of total. How can I modify the query?

Please don't flag it as duplicate, as I have to modify things within this query to get the desired result. The query building is done dynamically with windows application user selection.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytemptable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #mytemptable;

SELECT
    SUM(CAST([PT_100SCALED_VAL0] AS bigint)) AS PT_100SCALED_VAL0_TOTAL INTO #MYTEMPTABLE
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1.[timestamp],
        t1.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0]
    FROM [REPORT] t1
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, t1.[timestamp]) = @timestamp
) TEMPTABLE

SELECT
    t1.[timestamp],
    t1.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0],
    RM_temp.*
FROM    [REPORT] t1,
        #MYTEMPTABLE RM_temp
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE, t1.[timestamp]) = @timestamp
```

My present result is like below:

```
[timestamp]             [PT_100SCALED_VAL0] PT_100SCALED_VAL0_TOTAL
31/May/2016 12:01:37 PM 1                   87173
31/May/2016 12:02:07 PM 2                   87173
31/May/2016 12:02:37 PM 3                   87173
31/May/2016 12:03:07 PM 4                   87173
```

I want it to be:

```
[timestamp]             [PT_100SCALED_VAL0] PT_100SCALED_VAL0_TOTAL
31/May/2016 12:01:37 PM  1                  1
31/May/2016 12:02:07 PM  2                  3
31/May/2016 12:02:37 PM  3                  6
31/May/2016 12:03:07 PM  4                  10
```

Comment: May I suggest that you use explicit joins in your query, which make it easier to read?

Comment: I'm confused by your question title - "without changing the query" - if we cannot change the query, what do you expect us to do? If there are perhaps some *parts* of your logic which are alterable and some parts which cannot change, please make it explicitly clear in your question what we're allowed to edit.

Comment: can i do the running total calculation when inserting into temp table "#MYTEMPTABLE" of my query is what i meant. as the answer provided by @JaydipJ

Comment: You should be able to get the running total using a correlated subquery, assuming there are no ties in the value of `timestamp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *,(SELECT SUM(pp.PT_100SCALED_VAL0) 
          FROM YourTable pp 
          WHERE pp.PT_100SCALED_VAL0 <= p.PT_100SCALED_VAL0
         ) AS RunningTotal
FROM YourTable p
```

I have updated your `INSERT INTO` with following

```
SELECT
      (SELECT SUM(CAST(t2.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0] AS bigint)) 
       FROM  [REPORT] t2 
       WHERE t2.PT_100SCALED_VAL0 <= TEMPTABLE.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0] AND CONVERT(DATE, TEMPTABLE.[timestamp]) = @timestamp 
       )   AS PT_100SCALED_VAL0_TOTAL INTO #MYTEMPTABLE
FROM (
SELECT
    t1.[timestamp],
    t1.[PT_100SCALED_VAL0]
FROM [REPORT] t1
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, t1.[timestamp]) = @timestamp
) TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: i know this way of doing can i introduce this at this line "SELECT
    SUM(CAST([PT_100SCALED_VAL0] AS bigint)) AS PT_100SCALED_VAL0_TOTAL INTO #MYTEMPTABLE
FROM (" of my present query. if yes suggest me how to do it

Comment: @tan is it possible to provide sample data for more info

Comment: i am getting error "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "t1.PT_100SCALED_VAL0" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "t1.timestamp" could not be bound."  it cant read t1 from the sub query

Comment: @Tan Check Updated Ans

Comment: i just realised the same and updated and checked the result, by the time you have updated the answer. its working now, thank you.

Comment: but i run the query the loop is not stopping its keep on adding rows...i have 4000 records it has added nearly 7 lakh records and continuing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113611/discussion-between-tan-and-jaydipj).